# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT tblorder.fld_userid
FROM `tblordereditems`
inner JOIN tblorder ON tblorder.fld_id = tblordereditems.fld_order_id
where (SELECT sum( tblordereditems.fld_product_quantity )FROM tblordereditems inner JOIN tblorder ON tblorder.fld_id =tblordereditems.fld_order_id GROUP BY tblorder.fld_userid)>5
```

this is my query but throws an error .Can any body help ?Thanks

There are three tables here.

1. tbluser
2. tblorder
3. tblordereditems

The field fld_id of tbluser is foreign key to tblorder as fld_userid.
The fld_id of tblorder is foreign key to tblordereditems as fld_order_id  and i got to get the result fld_userid who has ordered more than 5 quantity of products,ie. sum of fld_product_quantity grouping them  by tblorder.fld_userid

Comment: It counts sum for each group because of GROUP BY

Comment: I think the error message says it all. Your subquery, the part between the `WHERE` clause and `>5` returns more than one row and you're trying to compare them all to `5`.

Answer (score 1):

it returs more than 1 row because you are requesting the count of all users.

try:

```
Select tb1.fld_userid
FROM `tblordereditems` tbi1
inner JOIN tblorder tb1 ON tb1.fld_id = tbi1.fld_order_id
where (
        SELECT sum( tbi2.fld_product_quantity ) 
        FROM tblordereditems tbi2 inner JOIN tblorder tb2 ON tb2.fld_id =tbi2 .fld_order_id 
         where tb2.fld_userid = tb1.fld_userid
)>5
```

Comment: u don't need  GROUP BY  tb2.fld_userid here in subquery

Comment: you're right, I copy&paste his code :P, thanks! I'm editing it

Comment: i tried but still it doesn't work instead it returns all the orders orderd by user each time.I want the orders by having grouped according to the users not each time the user orders

Comment: if you put `where tb2.fld_userid = tb1.fld_userid` in the subquery it can't return all the orders of all users...